# Validation of Text field not working

Tags: javascript

I have html page with checkboxes and text fields and the JavaScript is able to validate the 
checkboxes but not the textfields. Can someone help as I am not sure where it is wrong

```
<html>  
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function validator()
    {
        var c = document.getElementsByName("chk");
        var k=false;
          for( var i=0; i<c.length; i++ )
          { 
            if( c[i].checked ) 
            {
               k=true;
              return(true);
            }
          }
      if(k){
              return(true);
              }
              else{
                alert("Select one environment");
                return(false);
              }
          var ap = form.getElementById("a1");
          if(ap.value == "" || ap.length == 0)
         {
        alert("Enter the path");
        ap.setfocus();
        return(false);
         }
          else
          {
            return(true);
          }

                    var p = form.getElementById("a2");
          if(p.value == "" || p.length == 0)

         {
        alert("Enter the path");
        form.p.setfocus();
        return(false);
        }


        return(true);
            }


          </script>
      </head>

     <body>
    <form action="/car.java" onsubmit="return validator(this);">
        <br />
        <p>
            <input name="chk"  type="checkbox" />One
            <input name="chk"  type="checkbox" />Two
            <input name="chk"  type="checkbox" />Three
        </p>
        <br />
        <input name="a1" id="a1" size="123" style="width: 766px; height: 21px;" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input name="a2" id="a2" size="123" style="width: 766px; height: 21px;" 
                type="text" />
        </p>
        <textarea cols="95" name="status" rows="11"></textarea>
        <input name="sub" size="28" style="width: 156px; height: 29px;" type="button"
       value="Submit" />
        </p>
        </form>
         </body>  
       </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on your function, you are returning a value before the program finish with the textfield validation. You need to capture the return value on a variable and return its value just once at the end of the method.

something like this

```
function validator() {
var c = document.getElementsByName("chk");
var k = false,
    isValid = false;
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if (c[i].checked) {
        k = true;
    }
}
if (k) {
    isValid = true;
} else {
    alert("Select one environment");
}
var ap = form.getElementById("a1");
if (ap.value == "" || ap.length == 0) {
    alert("Enter the path");
    ap.setfocus();
} else {
    isValid = true;
}
var p = form.getElementById("a2");
if (p.value == "" || p.length == 0)
{
    alert("Enter the path");
    form.p.setfocus();
}
return isValid;
}
```

Comment: can you let me know in which part of the code I should make the change

Comment: Still it throws the "Select one environment" and goes to the next page. It doesn't throw alerts for textboxes

Comment: Made some changes and now if I select the checkbox and don't fill the text boxes, it throws the alert and goes to the page in form action which it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ap.value == "" || ap.length == 0)
```

I think you meant `ap.value.length == 0`, but either way it's redundant since you already checked for the empty string. Just `if(!ap.value)` will do. Additionally, you are `return`ing before the textbox part is even running.

That said, you should consider using HTML5 Form Validation. It's cleaner and will prevent such problems.